Prove $ab = ba \quad \text{iff} \quad aba^{-1} = b.$ Can I do this? $aba^{-1} = b \iff aba^{-1}a = ba \iff ab = ba$
In Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, there is this exercise:
($(G,*)$ is a group)

For $a,b \in G$, prove that $ab = ba \quad \text{iff} \quad aba^{-1} = b.$
(The abbreviation iff stands for "if and only if." Thus, first prove
that if $ab = ba$, then $aba^{-1} = b$. Next, prove that if
$aba^{-1} = b$, then $ab = ba$. Proceed roughly as in Exercise A.
Thus, assuming $ab = ba$, solve for $b$. Next, assuming $aba^{-1} =
 b^{-1}$, solve for $ab$.)

I wondered instead of proving both direction, can we do this?
$aba^{-1} = b \iff aba^{-1}a = ba \iff ab = ba$
I believe these statements are equivalent as we can go from the RHS to the LHS in the exact steps. If this is true, then it seems more elegant than the approach suggested by the author. Am I missing something?

Yes, you can do that.

This is the same as what the author did. You just used the biconditional.

Thank you everyone!

Don't you need to put brackets? That takes some more steps, but it forces you to clearly demonstrate that you understand the force of associativity.

@Dominique My prof did that in the first few demos but I noticed he dropped the parentheses when it was obvious which two elements were being considered at a particular step so I learned to do the same. :D

Oooh, that's dangerous! On the exam I would recommend you to use them anyway, or at least to explicitly mention that, in order to be strictly correct, you might need to add them.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

$aba^{-1}=b \implies aba^{-1}a = ba$ as $c=c\implies ca=ca$.  But why does $aba^{-1}=b\Leftarrow aba^{-1}a=ba$?  I suppose because $aba^{-1}a = ba\implies aba^{-1}aa^{-1} = baa^{-1}\implies aba^{-1}=b$.  But I don't think at this simple level of proof such a step can be considered "obvious" or "can be done in one's head".  Still at any level of proof above this it'd be obvious.  I can't say you are doing anything wrong (you arent'). But... be careful.

Yes, what the author is stating is the same as your proof.
For $\Rightarrow$, you first use that we can multiply to the left by the same element and, second, you use the definition of the identity element to cancel $a^{-1}a$.
For $\Leftarrow$, you first use the definition of the identity element and then the cancellation property, since you end up in both sides an $a$ multiplying to the left.
I believe the author propose doing it step by step to make sure the reader uses any property carefully, since this exercise introduces to the fundamentals of group theory. For example, as noted by Dominique in the comments, the use of the associative property is omitted in the proof. Hence, I would suggest, even if it is too elemental, justifying every single step in order to make sure the definitions are understood.
